Different speed of RandomInteger depending on syntax?
Consider the two commands:
RandomInteger[3, 10^7]; // RepeatedTiming
RandomInteger[{1, 3}, 10^7]; // RepeatedTiming

The first executes by a factor of 3 faster than the second one: 0.13 vs 0.37 on my machine. However, they return different sets: the first one ranges from 0 to 3, while the second one from 1 to 3.
Could you please tell me what is the reason for this difference in performance and how to make the first code generate from 1 to 3 without harming the performance (RandomInteger[2, 10^7]+1 slows down by a factor of 6)?

The 1st run may have been loading dependencies in the background.  Run again in same session and it should show the 1st as faster.  I'm on Mma 14.1 Win 11 and the 1st run was slower only on 1st run.

@Edmund : sorry, I mismatched "the first" and "the second" in the initial version of the question.

Probably the second is doing some arithmetic. At least both are faster than 1 + RandomInteger[2, 10^7]; // RepeatedTiming. An internal Trace reveals absolutely nothing. So the only ones who can answer are at WRI, unless details have been publicly shared at a WTC.

The following takes a few minutes to run, but it shows how the speed differs with range although not why. Perhaps someone knows a standard algorithm that chunks data or otherwise takes a performance hit at powers of 2. In any case, I didn't expect this:
Table[
  RandomInteger[k, 10^6]; // RepeatedTiming // First,
  {k, 100}] //
 ListLinePlot[#, GridLines -> {2^Range[6], None}] &



Maybe for a range of length $n$, the algorithm generates integers in the range $0$ to $2^k-1$, for the smallest $k$ such that $n \le 2^k-1$. Then it filters out integers that are greater than $n$. Such an algorithm would perform poorest when $n=2^k$ and improve as $n$ gets nearer $2^{k+1}$, since the percentage of rejections would decrease.

I guess I meant it would perform poorest when $n$ is a certain power of 2, namely, $n=2^{k-1}$ in the meaning of $k$ at the beginning of my comment. Then the length of the desired range $[0,n]$ is $2^{k-1}+1$ and the length of the generated range would be $2^k$, so that nearly half the candidates would be rejected on average. If that's how it works...

Your graph shows pretty much what you are surmising. Each power of two requires generating one more bit (at least using the default method), and as one approaches the next larger power the fraction of discards drops.
